# Error - Unable to create requested service

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

Estoy intentando conectarme desde una aplicación `java` con `hibernate` a una base `mysql` y me arroja este error.

He visto varia páginas pero aun no logro solucionarlo.

> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>           at com.nico.hibernate.ConecctionTest.pruebaDeConexion_ok(ConecctionTest.java:17)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
>           at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
>           at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
>           at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
>           at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
>           at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.(PooledConnections.java:20)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
>           ... 30 more
>       Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:673)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1084)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
>           ... 45 more
>       Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3052)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:597)
>           ... 59 more

Las librerias que uso son:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

y mi hibernate.cfg.xml es:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">testbd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/testbd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

Conexión:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: puedes agregar la conexion que estas utilizando o la instancia? al parecer no esta inicado el servicio de mysql. o tiene algun tipo de seguridad para restringir las conecciones entrantes tu base de datos

Comment: puse mas en detalle mi cofig.

Comment: intenta usar otro dialecto en la configuración de hibernate

Answer (score 1):

En tu stacktrace te dice que `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`, lo que indica que tu aplicación no puede conectar con el servidor de base de datos. Esto puede ser porque el servidor no esté iniciado o porque hayas configurado incorrectamente los parámetros de conexión.

Viendo que en tu session-factory has indicado que la connection.url es `jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/testbd`, todo parece indicar que el problema está ahí, ya que MySQL, por defecto, escucha en el puerto 3306 y no en el 8080 (que es el típico en el que escucha un servidor Tomcat o similar).

Cambia esa configuración por esta

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd</property>
```

Comment: he probado con el puerto 3306 pero me arroja el mismo error, sería el mismo puerto que uso cuando entro al phpmyadmin?

Comment: La unica diferencia cuando uso el puerto 3306 en la consola es esta `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)`